# how work with edit text and unicode?

Tags: java, android, xml, unicode, replace

This is my activity when run activity is stopped.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    final String a = "a";
    final String b = "b";
    final String c = "c";
    final String d = "d";
    final String e = "e";
    final String f = "f";
    final String g = "g";
    final String h = "h";
    final String a1 = "\u24B6";
    final String b1 = "\u24B7";
    final String c1 = "\u24B7";
    final String d1 = "\u24B9";
    final String e1 = "\u24BB";
    final String f1 = "\u24BB";
    final String g1 = "\u24BD";
    final String h1 = "\u24BD";
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {
            String name = et.getText().toString();
            name = name.replaceAll(a,a1);
            name = name.replaceAll(b, b1);
            name = name.replaceAll(c, c1);
            name = name.replaceAll(d, d1);
            name = name.replaceAll(e, e1);
            name = name.replaceAll(f, f1);
            name = name.replaceAll(g, g1);
            name = name.replaceAll(h,h1);
            tv.setText(name.trim());

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

what is the solution?

Please write correct code because all code in stack overflow is mistake.

Please help me with this problem as it is very hard.

Comment: Where's the problem? Post some stack trace.

Comment: I swear, I saw the same code a few days back too.

Comment: Telling the problem is very hard twice won't really help us solve it. Share what you are trying to do with your code. What is the current output and what is the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URLEncoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

```
String encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(yourInputString, "UTF-8");
```

Then decode with [URLDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html) as needed on wherever you will use it.